# Problems accessing var in kotlin object (singleton)

Tags: android, kotlin, object, singleton, var

Having this object:

```
object BarManager {
    private var bars = mutableMapOf<String, Bar>()
}
```

Can't access `bars` like this:

```
BarManager.bars[name]
```

It gives me this error:

> Cannot access 'bars': it is private in 'BarManager'

Supposedly, as per the Kotlin Properties and Fields documentation, each mutable (i.e., var) property has a getter and setter automatically created for it. Therefore there's no reason to auto generate getters and setters for Kotlin code.

So... whats happening here?

Comment: Visiblity of generated accessor methods is defined by property itself which in your case is private. Compiler will generate a private backing field, you don't have to declare it yourself.

Comment: Properties are more like methods (getters/setters) than fields. If you do `private var` that means you want private accessors. `public var` does exactly what you need - public accessors and private backing field.

Comment: What do you think `private` means?

Comment: Just remove the `private` keyword, as `public` is the default visibility modifier in Kotlin.

Comment: "The visibility you put in front of the property is the visibility of those generated accessors, not the backing fields. Backing fields are always private" That is exactly what I was searching for. I didn't know that. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The visibility you put in front of the property is the visibility of those generated accessors, not the backing fields. Backing fields are always private (and only directly usable outside accessors when using the K2 compiler; will be official in Kotlin 2.0). *Exception* to this is when you mark the property with `@JvmInline`, but this doesn't change how the property is treated in Kotlin code, only how it is compiled and seen from Java code.

So when you put `private var`, that means the getter and setter are both private. Remove the `private` keyword to make your getter and setter public (the default visibility).

Comment: "The visibility you put in front of the property is the visibility of those generated accessors, not the backing fields. Backing fields are always private" That is exactly what I was searching for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You've set visibilty of `bars` to private, so it isn't accessible outside of your BarManager object.

Just remove the `private` modifier.

```
object BarManager {
     var bars = mutableMapOf<String, Bar>()
}
```

It might be that you can also declare that property as a `val` since it doesn't appear to require mutability.

```
object BarManager {
     val bars = mutableMapOf<String, Bar>()
}
```

If for some reason it needs to be a mutable reference within BarManager but you don't want it the reference to be changed from outside of BarManager, you can do this

```
object BarManager {
     val bars = mutableMapOf<String, Bar>()
     private set
}
```